# Define $\varphi:S_4\to S_4$ via $\alpha\mapsto(1 3 4)\alpha$. How would I prove $\varphi$ is not a homorphism?

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, group-homomorphism

I have done practice problems like this in $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ to $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$ defined via $x \mapsto 3x$, but when it comes to $S_4$ I get tripped up. Can someone help me understand the process?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** Every group homomorphism maps the identity element into the identity element.

Comment: Thanks got it!!